# Tools to help prove to a customer web application latency is from their network

Tags: performance, webservice-client, latency

I need to be able to prove to a customer that the latency issues he is having is as a result of their slow internet or that this is nothing to do with my service. The customer is trying to access a web application hosted in the UK. The customer is based in China

Thanks

Comment: There are millions of speedtests out there. Select one from the UK and let the customer run the test

Answer (score 0):

I dont think you need to prove this to anyone, If you customer is in China and accessing application hosted in UK then obviously latency is major performance factor.

what you can do is get time of your method using any profiler(maybe google search will help you in this) and get execution time of your method in below environments,

1. In your local development environment (Lowest time)
2. In your local deployment environment (Very low)
3. In production i.e. in UK (High)

and present it to customer, Numbers will do the task for you. 
Here only network is different, all other aspects are same or comparable i.e. HW of server,SW you are developing, load on server etc.

you can do it with profilers,webbrowser plugins,as well as speed testing websites also.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use a tool like [Pingometer](http://pingometer.com) for this.

When you create a monitor, it will measure the latency of a site/application from different locations (e.g. Japan, Australia, the Netherlands, the United Kingdom, etc.).

I find the charts (under Reports) helpful since they plot the latency each day for historical comparison.